# Links work in MkDocs but not on GitHub repo

Tags: html, github, hyperlink, markdown, mkdocs

I am trying to put an image on my MkDocs webpage like this:

```
<div align="center">
 <img src=/../../images/img1.PNG>
 <img src=/../../images/img2.PNG>
 <figcaption>Fig1 (left), Fig2 (right)!</figcaption>
</div>
```

Which works fine. However, when I upload this to GitHub, the images don't show up. Is there a way to change the links so that they work on GitHub and MkDocs webpage? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by doing this:

```
![](../../images/img1.PNG#smallimg) ![](../../images/img2.PNG#smallimg)

_Fig1 (left), Fig2 (right)!_
```

And then adding a style tag at the bottom of the page:

```
<style>
img[src*="#bigimg"] {
   width:100%;
}
img[src*="#smallimg"]{
    width:45%;
}
</style>
```